# NetworkX subgraph: only keep connected nodes

Tags: networkx

I am trying to create a new directed `networkX` graph given a directed `networkX` graph and a `node_id` as input.
What I would like to do is the only keep the connected nodes to the `node_id` parameter on the subgraph. Some example:

**current networkX graph:**

```
node_id | edge_to 
france    spain, germany, italy, belgium
spain     france, portugal
portugal  spain
germany   france, netherlands, belgium
```

**the function I would like to implement:**

```
new_graph = get_subgraph(graph='graph', node_id='spain')
```

**new graph:**

```
node_id | edge_to 
france    spain, germany, italy, belgium
spain     france, portugal
portugal  spain
```

Comment: You can look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734399/how-do-i-create-network-graph-from-an-adjacency-matrix-for-specific-nodes-only/57740538#57740538) and run the `neigh` function with depth 2.

Comment: thanks! What is the depth can be 2 or greater?

Comment: depth two would give you everything within a two step distance from the staring point, which is what you were asking for in your question.